# What is the purpose of the "plasma" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plasma/info) says:

> Plasma physics as applied to fusion energy, astrophysics, semiconductor equipment development

I'm not sure how any of this is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

But when looking at the list of questions ([currently 63](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plasma)), the tag is mostly not used like this anyway.

In the majority of the cases the tag is used to refer to the KDE Plasma desktop environment (but for which there already is [kde-plasma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde-plasma)).

Other uses seem to refer to

- The ["Plasma In-Memory Object Store"](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/plasma.html) of Apache Arrow.
- Other libraries or frameworks which I've never heard of which have "Plasma" in their name.

Comment: Ugh, [bad edit suggestion and reviewers are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12462415)...

Comment: @AndrewT. Oh boy. One would think people actually read what their co-reviewers write...

Comment: From just an hour before your post, we have one person using the tag correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66887848/creating-an-absorption-spectrum

Comment: @TRiG what a coincidence ;) that question triggered my post here

Comment: [tag:kde-plasma] exists. Base on the comment by @AndrewT., maybe remove [tag:plasma] entirely and replace with [tag:kde-plasma] where relevant.

Comment: [tag:plasma] was derezzed? How much energy did that take?

Comment: @AndrewT. I twisted three frontal lobes reading that

Comment: @EgorHans Ahem, no, reviewers don’t get to see what other reviewers did. That’s how the system ensures independent review decisions instead of getting reviewers just following the first reviewer or the majority.